# Simple remote XML fails with JasperReports Server

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports

Im trying to create a report with a very simple xml file that has to be displayed.

http://scdn.flowl.info/2013-004-flowl/security/ip_blacklist.xml

iReports does actually read the file and gives me its structure. But no matter in what way I define the fields, on hitting preview, it always says '0 records read'.

I tried with `*`, `/blacklist`,  `/blacklist/ip`, `@blacklist`, `@ip`, `/`, ... no matter what I enter, it gives me no records and an empty report.

System info:

```
Product Version: Jaspersoft iReport Designer 5.1.0
Java: 1.7.0_21; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 23.21-b01
System: Windows 8 Version 6.2 läuft auf x86; Cp1252; de_DE (ireport)
```

Any suggestions?

[image: iReport screenshot]

Comment: Try this:  <queryString language="xPath">
  <![CDATA[*/ip]]>
 </queryString>
 <field name="datetime" class="java.lang.String">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@datetime]]></fieldDescription>
 </field>
 <field name="source" class="java.lang.String">
  <fieldDescription><![CDATA[@source]]></fieldDescription>
 </field>

Comment: It works fine. You can try with Preview mode in *iReport*

Comment: I tried that, I still don't get any results and the error is still 'The document has no pages'

Comment: I think the problem in datasource configuration. I've tried your xml - everything is ok

Comment: In *iReport* I've used *Use the report XPath expression when filling the report* option for *XML file datasource*.

Comment: The option is not available for me for remote XML files, only for local XML.